# cURL to domain on same [CentOS 5.5] server

Tags: php, curl, apache2, centos5

I've got a utility domain out there (let's call it utility-domain.com) that generates short URLs and a site (let's call it prod-domain.com) that is attempting to call utility-domain.com to generate a short URL for it. They are on the same LAMP server, running CentOS 5.5. This is actually going to be a cURL in a PHP script, but before I get there, I am trying to just do a simple `curl http://utility-domain.com` while ssh'd into the server to see if it will resolve. I'm getting an error of `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`. I've set the `/etc/hosts` file to point utility-domain.com to `127.0.0.1`, and confirmed with a ping while ssh'd in that it is resolving to the local IP. Any ideas on how to get this to resolve?

I realize running this code locally would be better than doing a cURL to it, but the utility domain is used in other remote applications, so I'm trying to keep the scripts in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the 'utility-domain' resolved (as otherwise curl would fail differently) but the curl error explains that there was no TCP server listening to port 80 on the IP that curl tried to connect to. You can easily verify this by checking which IP curl decided to use and then you can try telnetting to that IP + port instead of using curl.

This problem can be due to many reasons but possibly your Apache is not configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 (or "any" or whatever) so you have to make sure to reach correct IP. Or you have to modify your server config.

In some configurations, the IP of a host internally is not the same as the IP shown externally and that can also make things a bit tricky when you try to access your site without going through the external means.